# TFT35 and G-code preview

Tags: g-code, bigtreetech, display

Is there a way to have the Bigtreetech TFT35 v3.0 show a G-code preview while printing - similar to the MKS TFT35?

Comment: Could you please expand the question, possibly with images, what is meant by previewing G-code while printing?

Comment: What Firmware are you using? Because you need to modify the firmware.

Comment: If this is related to print preview image, the MKS has a dedicated software/firmware release showing a preview of the model (probably generated from G-code). It might be the case that the Bigtreetech is an older fork of that branch, you could look into that.

Comment: I'm using version x.x.25 and I've made the changes in the firmware that I've found that relate to g-code preview, but I just get a blank icon displaying and now there is a long filename error when using the SD on the main board. I suspect there are other places to make changes in the firmware, but I am not finding them - I was hoping somebody else had experience with this.